# Is there functions that satisfy these conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I need 2 functions ($f(x)$ and $g(x)$) that satisfy these conditions:

$f(x) > g(x) \;\; \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$

and

$f'(x) < g'(x) \;\; \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$

I can't find any and I have this justification:

$$f(x)>g(x) \iff f(x) - g(x) > 0 \iff (f(x) - g(x))' > 0 \iff f'(x) > g'(x)$$

Is this correct? Or are there functions that satisfy the conditions?

Comment: The derivative of a positive function need not be positive.

Comment: It is not true that $h(x)>0\implies h'(x)>0$.  Take $e^{-x}$ for example.

Comment: $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: @AlexSilva That f(x) = e^-x just enlightened me! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Try $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and an increasing function closely related to it. The spoiler-protected block gives you the other function if you can’t find it after some thought.

> Specifically, you can take $g(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: That f(x) = e^-x just enlightened me! Thanks

Comment: @Carlos: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you call $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ you are looking for $h(x)>0$ and $h'(x)<0$. An easy example is $h(x)=a^{x}$ with $0<a<1$.

Now you can think about many $f$ and $g$. For example, $f(x)=2a^x$ and $g(x)=a^x$.